# How to split a string into substring Arduino

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, sketch

I'm about identify myself stupid, howcome I couldn' t figure out how to split a string into substring using arduino, even after 10 days of searching. The number is fact... So, As Mr.Arduino.cc says: *string*.substring() is just can be used as conditional phrase with loops like if. and there is no method such strtok() like in C can help me with this. So guys, I' m bagging you for help, please!

```
if (ks > 255 * 60)
            {
                    vek.print("Bu yazı, ", 25, 0);
                    vek.printNumI(255*60, 25, 8);
                    vek.print("karakterd-", 25, 16);
                    vek.print("en uzun ol", 25, 24);
                    vek.print("dugundan", 25, 32);
                    vek.print("gosterlemz", 25, 40);
            }

for (byte i = 0; i <= ss ; i ++)
            {
                    for (byte j = 0; j <= 6; j++)
                    {
                            int ilk_kar = j * 10 + i * 60;
                            int son_kar = ilk_kar + 10;

                            String yaz=readString.strtok(ilk_kar,son_kar);

                            vek.print(yaz, 25, j);

                            if (analogRead(A5) == 1023)
                            {
                                    continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Error: sketch_aug22a.ino: In function ‘void loop()’:
sketch_aug22a.ino:83:56: error: ‘class String’ has no member named ‘strtok’

What am I supposed to do?

Thanks, already...

Comment: Do you want to split the string on a particular character or position?

Comment: You can use `strtok()`. It's not part of the Arduino core library: it's just a libc function.

Comment: And, how am I supposed to find that libc (I guess a library) thing?

Comment: Mr.Bonet, pls, I need this answer...

Comment: It would help to have the above questions answered. Do you want to split at  a certain spot (eg. 5th character)? Or after certain symbols (eg. a comma)?

Comment: How do you find `strtok`? Google? For example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Comment: *there is no method such strtok() like in C can help me with this* - yes, there is. Just use it. No need to include any extra libraries or anything. Why do you think there is "no method"? Did you try it?

Comment: I did, I have edited my question. please check that out

Comment: `strtok()` is not a method, it's a plain function that works on C strings (`char *`), not on `String` objects. Nick Gammon googled the doc for you, you should take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Import the *string.h* library by adding `#include <string.h>` on top of your sketch, in order to use the `strtok()` function.
Checkout the usage example of `strtok()` here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok

Comment: in arduino ide?

Comment: Yes, of course.